# How to define a function that accepts any functions as a parameter whose return type is T?

Tags: dart

How to define a function that accepts any functions as a parameter whose return type is `T` ?

For example, let's say, there is a function `foo` :

```
void foo<F extends int Function(___)>(F f) { ... } // what should ___ be?
```

Then, `foo` accepts any functions as a parameter `f` that returns `int` such as `(int x, int y) => x * y` , `(String x) => int.parse(x)`.

How could I write such kind of functions in Dart?

Comment: You cannot.  Even if you could do this, it wouldn't accomplish much since you still would need to rely on runtime checks when you actually pass arguments to the function.

Comment: You cannot do this, as @jamesdlin says. However, *if you could*, it would actually be useful, because then it would be possible to do that to the first argument of `Function.apply`, which allows you to dynamically call the function, but you'd know the return type for sure. That's still something.

Comment: Where is the `T` in your function definition? It should be possible to define `void foo<T>(T Function() f) {}` but of course this does not allow passing any arguments to `f`. Maybe we can better help if you state your intended use of this construct.

Comment: @Ber, the above example is for the case where `T` is `int`. I just wanted to know that it is possible to achive the same thing as Typescript's `Parameters` type in Dart. Well, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve something similar using the [Invocation class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Invocation-class.html).

```
void foo<T>(Invocation f) {...}

int baz(int a, int b) => a+b;

void main() {
  foo(Invocation.method(#baz, [2, 3]));
}
```

`#baz` creates an Instance of `Symbol` for the function `baz`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. But I wanted to do the thing in a type safe manner.

Comment: @fuji Maybe you should ask a question around the purpose you actually want to achieve. Your question seems to focus on a specific solution you have in mind. The more open your question is, the broader (and more useful) the answers will be.